# How do I know which modules are associated with ActiveRecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having some difficulty locating where methods invoked on ActiveRecord instances are defined.  Usually they come from some mixed-in module, but I can't even find documentation indicating which modules are mixed in.  Is there documentation anywhere that lists the modules that are mixed into ActiveRecord?  Or do I have to open up base.rb to find out?

This is actually just a specific instance of dealing with Rails in general- if I want to find where a method is defined, how to I go about looking for it?  Do most people go straight to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails source code can be convoluted for sure. When I get lost I start by going to the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and just do a Ctrl-F and look for the method name. What is the specific method you are asking about?

Comment: Or even better, download [Rails Searchable API Doc](http://railsapi.com/). You can do smart search (doesn't have to be exact, `habtm` will match `has_and_belongs_to_many`), and it's local, so it's fast.

Comment: Rails API is nice, as are some of the other suggestions in the responses.  Thanks.  I was looking for the toggle! method.  So, perhaps a follow-up question; if I want to find all the methods I can call on an ActiveRecord instance, how can I do that?  Rails API lets me locate where a particular method is located, but if I want to see a list of methods that can be invoked on an instance (or at the class level), how do I do that?

Comment: @htanata - the Rails Searchable API Doc is nice, but I have a hard time finding the overviews of the classes and modules that the regular API provides.

Comment: @Jergason You can browse the class list or search for it (although it's not intuitive). For example, if you search `base activerecord` you'll get the main documentation for Active Record. But if you want to search for Ruby's String class, then the correct result is actually the second one. For myself, I eventually get used to it and know which result is the right one.